# Mass of shards with the the cell fracture add-on

Tags: add-on, rigid-body-simulation

Using the cell fracture add-on I create shards of different sizes, and I want to use them in a rigid body simulation. I have the option to set the mass of the shards based on their volume:

[image]

The problem is that I don't know how to access these masses. The shards don't have rigid body physics activated, and if I activate rigid body physics on them, then their mass will be the default 1.000, independent on their size.

I saw a tutorial where the guy went into "Blender Game" mode, and indeed if I do it, I see the expected mass values on the shards. But I don't want to use "Blender Game" - I am not interested in game development. I would like to have these masses with Cycles and normal rigid body physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setting is located in the *properties panel>physics>rigid body tab*.
[image]

[image]

You may also go to the *tool panel>physics tab,* (while in object mode) press <kbd>T</kbd> if it is not open already. Select *calculate mass*, and Blender will give you a host of preset values such as broken glass, iron, cardboard, etc.

[image]

Comment: As I wrote, my problem is that the shards don't have rigid body physics activated. Of course I can activate it, but then I need to set the values manually. Your second tip is useful, however, so I accept this answer.